# Resize array using new

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

So I am trying to resize an array by making a function call ResizeArray(). However, I don't know what is the correct way to use "delete" in this case. (I make a new int * and copy the value from the original to it and then I make the original pointer points to the new one, now I don't know what to "delete"

```
    class Base

        {
    private:
        int sizeInClass;
        int *arrayy=nullptr;

    public:
            Base(int s)
            {
             sizeInClass=s;
             arrayy = new int[s]{};
             setValue();
            };
        void setValue()
        {
             for(int x=0;x<sizeInClass;x++)
             {
             arrayy[x]=x;
             }
        }

        void print()
        {
             int countter=0;
             for(int x=0;x<sizeInClass;x++)
             {
             countter++;
             cout<<arrayy[x]<<endl;
             }
             cout<<"The size of the array is : "<<countter<<endl;
        }


        void ResizeArray(int newSize)
        {
            int *newArray = nullptr;

            newArray = new int[newSize];

                for(int x=0;x<sizeInClass;x++)
                {
                    newArray[x]=arrayy[x];
                }

            delete [] arrayy;    /////////////////////////////////// should i use deleate here ? 

            arrayy = newArray;

            delete [] newArray; /////////////////////////////////// or should I use deleate here ?

            sizeInClass = newSize;
        }



        ~Base()
        {
        delete [] arrayy;  /////////////////////////////////// or just use delete here
        arrayy=nullptr; 
        }

};


int main()
{

   Base b(5);
   b.print();
   b.ResizeArray(8);
   b.setValue();
   b.print();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why are you not simply using `std::vector`?

Comment: for learning purpose

Comment: [for learning purposes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ead0eeb7f930b6c4).  It is not as trivial as it looks.

Answer (score 0):

The first and the 3rd of your suggested `delete` are correct.

Comment: Thank you ! so it's ok to delete twice ( including the destructor )

Comment: You are not deleting the same memory twice. You are accessing different memory areas through the same pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding handling resources, 
for sure you need de-allocation in destructor, to free resources when your container class
is destroyed. When you want to resize contained array, you are handling it in ResizeArray function, so below is basic proposal for it, with clarification comments:

```
    void ResizeArray(int newSize)
    {
        int *newArray = new int[newSize];

        if (nullptr != newArray) { // we take action only if allocation was successful

            for(int x=0;x<sizeInClass;x++)
            {
                newArray[x]=arrayy[x];
            }
            delete [] arrayy;    // good, here you delete/free resources allocate previously for an old array 
            arrayy = newArray;   // good, you redirect member ptr to newly allocated memory


        /* delete [] newArray; ups, we have member ptr point to this location 
        and we cannot delete it, after this, accessing it would be UB, 
        beside in dtor we would have double, second deletion */

            sizeInClass = newSize;
        }
    }
```

Your destructor is fine.

There could be further improvements in your code, but this is related to your question.